# Generating multiple HTML fragments for a JSONP response (Spring MVC)

Tags: jsp, spring-mvc, jsonp, tiles

I have a JSONP service where I want to return several HTML fragments along with some other info.  I'd like to generate those fragments with an HTML template system.

The response might look something like this:

```
parseResponse({
    "id": "a684a87ea3sd8",
    "status": "OK",
    "some_list": "<ul><li>item one</li><li>item two</li></ul>",
    "summary": "<p>You have two items</p><p>You're so cool</p>",
    "another_list": "<ul><li>uno</li><li>dos</li><li>microsoft</li></ul>",
    "more_non_html_info": "And he stepped on the ball"
});
```

So using Spring 3 MVC, in my controller I'd like to be able to feed an object/context into my template system and get an HTML string back.  I want to do that a dozen or so times each time the controller is invoked.

I can't find a way to do this using JSP.  What's the most straight-forward way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

In your controller you should create a function building your json string

```
@Controller
public class MyController {
    ....
    public String myfunction(ModelMap model) {
        String jsonReply = "{"
              +"'id':'blabla',"
              +"'status':'blabla',"
              ....
              +"}";


       model.put('json',jsonReply);
       return 'myview';
}
```

Then create a view called 'myview.jsp' and in it only display the json object in your model

${json}

This is not the best way to do it but you can start here.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I don't see how I can generate and add the HTML fragments from the JSP using this approach.

Comment: Make an ajax call to you Controller to generate the json string. Then implement the parseResponse function in javascript to add the fragments in your calling JSP.